# How to find the angle between two straight line equations?

Tags: graphing-functions

### The Problem

There are two straight lines with equations as follow

> **y=-2x+10** and **y=-3x+6**

their point of intersection is (2,6) and i am asked to find the angle between them ?

*A detailed and easy explanation would be appriciated*

### Source and background

CIE/Cambridge International A and AS Level/Mathematics (9709)/Nov 2005 P1 Q9

(its part 3 i solved it a little before asking below is the whole question if needed)
[image: the question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$d_1:y=-2x+10\Rightarrow k_1=\tan\alpha_1=-2$$ and $$d_2:y=-3x+6\Rightarrow k_2=\tan\alpha_2=-3$$
then
$$\angle(d_1,d_2)=\alpha_1-\alpha_2=\arctan(\tan(\alpha_1-\alpha_2))=\arctan \frac{\tan\alpha_1-\tan\alpha_2}{1+\tan\alpha_1\tan\alpha_2}=$$

$$=\arctan\frac{k_1-k_2}{1+k_1k_2}=\arctan\frac{-2-(-3)}{1+(-2)(-3)}=\arctan\frac{1}{7}=0,14189..=8^{\circ} 07'48,37''$$

because
$$\arctan(\tan x)=x$$ and
$$\tan(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)=\frac{\tan\alpha_1-\tan\alpha_2}{1+\tan\alpha_1\tan\alpha_2}$$

Comment: Explanation? ${}{}{}$

Comment: how was ∠(d1,d2)=arctan(k1−k2)/(1+k1k) derived ??

Comment: pardon me for not getting it but by arctan do you mean tangent inverse or just tangent (in radians)

Comment: Edited and explained

Answer (score 4):

Try using this relationship. If a line has slope $m$, and the angle at which it hits the $x$-axis is $\theta$, then 
$$\tan(\theta) = m.$$

Comment: The relationship shown really did the thing thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

The slope of $y=-2x+10$ is $-2$, so it makes an angle of $\arctan (-2)$ with the $x$ axis.  Similarly the other has a slope of $-3$ and makes an angle of $\arctan (-3)$ with the $x$ axis.  The angle between them is $\arctan (-2)-\arctan(-3)\approx 0.1419$ radians.

Another approach is that a vector in the direction of the first line is $(1,-2)$ and one in the direction of the second is $(1,-3)$.  The dot product $(1,-2)\cdot (1,-3)=7=|(1,-2)||(1,-3)|\cos \theta=5\sqrt 2 \cos \theta$.  This gives $\theta=\frac 7{5\sqrt 2}\approx 0.1419$

Answer (score 1):

The slope of a line is equal to the tan of its angle of inclination (angle above the positive x axis.  So you can calculate that angle for each line and then find the difference.  That is my initial suggestion.

Comment: thanks your suggestion and @ncmathsadist given relation really helped :D